# Universal Windows App - I have a ListView of products, Add to Cart button.

Tags: c#, xaml

Needless to say, I am a beginner at Universal Windows Apps development, and I need help. I have a ListView with items representing products displayed as catalog. Each item includes 'Add to Cart' button. My question is: When the button is tapped, how do I pass the specific item for which the button has been tapped to a method which puts the product in the cart. Here is my xaml page:

```
<ListView Name="productsList">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>...
                        ....
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10">
                            <TextBlock Name="productName" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}" ></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Name="productPrice" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Price}" Margin="0,5" ></TextBlock>
                            <Button  Name="addToCart" Content="Stavi u korpu" FontSize="14" Tapped="addToCart_OnTapped" ></Button>
                        </StackPanel>...
                    ....
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

When the button 'addToCart' is tapped I would like to pass the item as parameter to the following method in C# code, which puts the product in shopping cart:

```
private void addToCart_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       // Code to put the product into a cart. This code is not important right now. What is important is how do I pass it a proper parameter?
    }
```

Comment: A very easy way is to add  your item as a Tag to the button `<Button Tag="{Binding .}" ..../>`. Then you can just get the tag in the event. `var button = (Button)sender; var obj = (Product)button.Tag;`

Comment: @user2657943 - Thank you so much. This does exactly what I want.

Comment: Long live the Internet and the good people who help others!!!

Comment: No problem. I'll write it here below so you can mark it as an answer.

Comment: I did mark it as the answer, but my reputation is too low, so it does not show on post score.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for a beginner to solve this is to pass your object as a Tag.

```
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10">
                        <TextBlock Name="productName" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}" ></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Name="productPrice" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Price}" Margin="0,5" ></TextBlock>
                        <Button  Name="addToCart" Tag="{Binding .}" Content="Stavi u korpu" FontSize="14" Tapped="addToCart_OnTapped" ></Button>
                    </StackPanel>
```

`Binding .` refers to the current object in your list.

So on your event you can get the specific button you clicked on, and get the it m out of the Tag.

```
var button = (Button)sender; 
var obj = (Product)button.Tag;
```